# How to exchange variables with reusable sub-process in JBPM 6.4.0?

Tags: java, jbpm, kie-wb

I wanted to improve the structure of my jbpm process and therefore tried to encapsulate some stuff in a reusable subprocess. Following the instructions in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.4.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch06.html#d0e3634), I first created a simple test-process to validate its behavior.

To achieve this, I defined the following:

A (parent-)process with 2 variables "sub_in" and "sub_out" of type String. 
A second (child-)process with 2 variables "in_sub" and "out_sub" of type String.

The parent process contains a Script Task, which sets "sub_in" to "input", a Sub-process Task (calling the child-process), and a second Script Task, which outputs the value of "sub_out".

The child-process contains a single Script Task, which outputs the value of "in_sub" and sets "out_sub" to "output".
Additionally I defined an I/O-mapping of (Name: "in_sub", Data Type: "String", Source "sub_in") and (Name "out_sub", Data Type: "String", Target: "sub_out").

Surprisingly, both scripts output *null* as value of the corresponding variable. Is this feature broken in version 6.4.0? Am I missing something?
I saw a similar question [on Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jbpm-usage/a5Xp874E4Wo), but without any reactions.

FYI: I am using a the Kie-Workbench and KIE Execution server (both Version 6.4.0.Final on two JBoss EAP 6.4 instances) to design and run the processes.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this on jBPM 6.5 beta 1 and it worked as expected.  In the script tasks make sure you set the variables like

```
kcontext.setVariable("sub_in", "input");
```

It could be broken in 6.4 - I know multi-instance subprocesses are broken in that load, fixed in 6.5 beta 1 (see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPM-5143)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have been on vacation for the last three weeks and will try using version 6.5 in the next few days. I will keep you updated.

Comment: My issue really seems to be related to the 6.4 Version, upgrading to 6.5 Beta1 resolved it. Thanks :)